# Render Rails responses as JSON... but keep Rails default HTTP response codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, http, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-4

When Rails responds to an HTTP request, it's HTTP response will always be correctly headed up with an appropriate HTTP response code.  This can be for successful operations (a 2xx code), such as the creation of a new ActiveRecord in the database, or for errors (a 4xx).  In the latter case a rendered HTML page is supplied containing information about the error (a backtrace, etc).

My app requires that all Rails HTTP responses take the form of JSON, so I am writing my own code to render these HTTP responses accordingly.  A number of tutorials talk about writing something like this to render such responses (in this example, located in `user_account_controller.rb` where `UserAccount` is the name of an ActiveRecord model):

```
# method to create a UserAccount object based on supplied user_account_params
def create
   @user_account = UserAccount.create!(user_account_params)
   if @user_account
       render :status => 201, :json => {
      'message' : 'Operation was successful!"
      }
   end
end
```

And, if an exception is thrown, it is possible to bind a customer exception handler as follows:

```
# In ApplicationController

rescue_from Exception, :with =>  :json_exception_handler

def json_exception_handler(exception)
    render :status => 422, :json => {
        :exception => {
            :backtrace => exception.backtrace,
            :message => exception.message
        }
    }
end
```

The problem with both of these solutions is that they require me to statically set the HTTP response codes to have the same value every time (201 and 422 in these examples).  Rails already does a great job of automatically picking the best response code to use, depending on the type of error or type of successful operation.  I don't want to have to reinvent the wheel badly by inventing my own response code structure for each error and operation in my app.

So my question is this: how do I supply the response code that Rails will have automatically chosen anyway, whilst retaining the ability to print out custom JSON?

Comment: You should be able to call `response.status`

Comment: If response.status is called within an exception handler it will always return 200, I guess because the exception has now been handled...